# Access function from parent

Tags: javascript

If I load a new script into my page is there a way to acess the already defined functions?

Like:

```
function parentFunction() {
    // do something
}
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "http://somedomain.com/somescript";
document.head.appendChild(s);

runScript();
```

When I tried the external script I got this:

```
function runScript(){
    alert('new code'); // this works
    parentFunction();  // Uncaught ReferenceError: parentFunction is not defined 
}
```

Comment: Is `parentFunction` inside of a closure?

Comment: Travis, yes it was. On a domready function :/ Nice catch... thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must export `parentFunction` outside the closure, making it global.

You can do that by setting it as a property of `window`:

```
function parentFunction() {
    // do something
}
window.parentFunction = parentFunction;
```

or shorter:

```
window.parentFunction = function() {
    // do something
};
```